# how to create a button that creates another button and show up immediately

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, button

I want to create a button that Creates other buttons and I want it to be able to create like infinite buttons on the screen
I tried

```
Button button = new Button();
button.Location = new Point(100,100);
button.Text = "IT Woreked";
button.Size = new Size(26,26);
button.Visible = true;
Application.Restart();
this.Controls.Add(button);
```

and I believe it really adds it but it's not shown up
so how do I add the button to the screen

Comment: `Application.Restart();` ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that is because you are putting all the new buttons in the same location. Also, remove the `Application.Restart()` part.

```
Button button = new Button();
button.Location = new Point(100,100); //change this to random or something 
button.Text = "IT Woreked";
button.Size = new Size(26,26);
button.Visible = true;
Application.Restart();//don't restart the application everytime you click!
this.Controls.Add(button);
```

You should also subscribe to the new buttons' OnClick event. You should create a local function that contains all the above code and subscribe to the new buttons. This way you can add buttons recursively. Say if the original button's name is `button1`, change its click method to something like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Random random = new Random(System.Environment.TickCount);//random location everytime
    Button button = new Button();
    button.Text = "IT Woreked";
    button.Size = new Size(26, 26);// the size might be a bit small. You might want to increase it.
    button.Location = new Point(random.Next(0, this.Size.Width - button.Width), random.Next(0, this.Size.Height - button.Height)); //change this to random or something 
    button.Visible = true;
    this.Controls.Add(button);
    button.Click += button1_Click;//when the new button is clicked, call this method.
}
```